# Is there a gremlin query which could help us return the value of a property of particular node in the graph

Tags: gremlin

Trying to get value of property of node.

Node: 
     id: 5
     status: true
     name: MyNode
Expected result is to achieve the value of status based on node id which is 5.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to study the documentation or other materials available to learn Gremlin. This is a very simple query.

```
g.V('5').values('status')
```

Cheers
Kelvin